# Problem with Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: emulation, windows-phone-7

I have updated my WP7 tools to mango(7.1) and after 3 days, I tried to change the Image copy of WP7 emulator to a hacked image copy. But it ddnt work. So that I replaced the actual image back to its folder. And from then, every time when I start the debugging for the first time, it displaying a message "windows phone emulator is doing a complete OS Boot.." for a long time and also showing an alert box "Internal Error".

And its working as usual when I close the Emulator and start debugging for the second or third  time. Can anybody tell what would be the problem and how to overcome it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as if something went wrong during the update. It could be one of a number of things and without actually being at your machine its hard to tell what.

Simplest and most effective fix is a complete uninstall then reinstall of VS and the SDK.